# How can I group variables from a mat file by name and collect them in a structure?

Tags: matlab, variables, mat-file, matlab-struct

I'm reading in a mat file which has variables with a counter e.g. `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `b`, `c1` and `c2`.

I want to put the data into a structure with field names "a", "b" and "c" where 
`a=[a1;a2;a3]`, `b=b` and `c = [c1; c2]`.

The algorithm needs to be able to do this, without knowing what the maximum value of the counter of each variable is. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would load your mat file data using the [`load`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html) function, placing it in a structure. Let's say that gave you the following sample data:

```
>> s = struct('a1',1:5,'b',[],'a2',1:5,'a3',1:5,'c1',1:3,'c2',3:5)
s = 
    a1: [1 2 3 4 5]
     b: []
    a2: [1 2 3 4 5]
    a3: [1 2 3 4 5]
    c1: [1 2 3]
    c2: [3 4 5]
```

Then, we'll order the fields alphabetically using [`orderfields`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html), find the field names using [`fieldnames`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html), use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to strip all trailing numbers off of the field names, then get the unique substrings using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
>> s = orderfields(s);
>> [strs, inds] = unique(regexprep(fieldnames(s), '\d*$', ''), 'last')
strs = 
    'a'
    'b'
    'c'

inds =
     3
     4
     6
```

Using the indices returned by [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), we can calculate how many times each substring appears by doing `diff([0; inds])`. Then, we group the structure data into a cell array using these counts and [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) and [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html):

```
>> data = mat2cell(struct2cell(s), diff([0; inds]))
data = 
    {3x1 cell}
    {1x1 cell}
    {2x1 cell}
```

Notice that we have a cell array of cell arrays. If you know for sure that each set of entries for each substring will concatenate properly (as in our example), you can concatenate them using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) as follows:

```
>> data = cellfun(@cell2mat, data, 'UniformOutput', false)
data = 
    [3x5 double]
    []
    [2x3 double]
```

Now we have a cell array of matrices, and a new structure can be made using [`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html):

```
>> snew = cell2struct(data, strs)
snew = 
    a: [3x5 double]
    b: []
    c: [2x3 double]
```

Comment: This methods works, but then the original structure needs to be in alphabetical order. If this isn't the case use [strs, inds] = unique(regexprep(fieldnames(s), '\d*$', ''), 'last'); [sortedInds, IX] = sort(inds); data = mat2cell(struct2cell(s), diff([0; sortedInds]));snew = cell2struct(data, strs(IX));

Comment: @user3097013: I mentioned using ORDERFIELDS in the text, I just didn't show it in the code. I've added that line.

Comment: Correct, but then "a10" is placed between "a1" and "a2". That's not the case if you do it with the sort command as in the first command.